# is it possible to change app bar text changes in tabbar selection on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the app bar text to change for each tab bar selection .
ex:

When I click on a designer tab I want the text of the app bar text to change to designer and when the next tab ,say painter is selected  the app bar text should change to painter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TabController` to listen to it. Then call setState whenever you are switching between the Tabs, and change the AppBar title accordingly

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

````
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home:new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  final List<MyTabs> _tabs = [new MyTabs(title: "BLABLABLA",color: Colors.teal[200]),
  new MyTabs(title: "Orange",color: Colors.orange[200])
  ];
  MyTabs _myHandler ;
  TabController _controller ;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _myHandler = _tabs[0];
    _controller.addListener(_handleSelected);
  }
  void _handleSelected() {
    setState(() {
       _myHandler= _tabs[_controller.index];
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(_myHandler.title),
        backgroundColor: _myHandler.color,
        bottom: new TabBar(
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              new Tab(text: _tabs[0].title,),
              new Tab(text: _tabs[2].title,)
            ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}

class MyTabs {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  MyTabs({this.title,this.color});
}```
````